# Keeping consistent property names in dynamic objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

So, I'm not sure where my head is at today but I can't wrap my head around a decent solution to this issue and I was hoping you guys can help.

We are building a .NET Core / EF Core / SQL application that hands a base record type, and then we layer on metadata objects on top of that base record to enrich the datasets. So my base class looks something like this:

```
    public class Record
    {
        [NotNull]
        public Guid Id { get; set }

        [CanBeNull]
        public virtual string InvoiceNum { get; set; }

        [CanBeNull]
        public virtual string Notes { get; set; }

        //Enum that defines the extra properties
        public virtual RecordType RecordType { get; set; }
        
        public Dictionary<string,object> ExtraProperties { get; set; }

    }
```

and my MetaData class looks something like this:

```
public class MetaData
{
    [NotNull]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
     
    [NotNull]
    public Guid RecordId { get; set; }

    [NotNull]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    //Enum that defines the extra properties
    public virtual MetaDataTypes MetaDataType { get; set; } 

    public Dictionary<string,object> ExtraProperties { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the ExtraProperties field in each object to store a JSON encoded string of additional data for each type, determined by the Enum values noted in the objects above.

What I am trying to find out, is how do I consistently (and efficiently) define those metadata fields on an incoming JSON without needing to hard code each individual type?

For example, I was thinking the JSON for a complete incoming record could be something like this:

```
{
  "Record" : {
    "InvoiceNum":"12345",
    "Notes":"Notes go here",
    "MetaData" : [
      { 
        "MetaDataType" : "Address",
        "Properties" : 
        {
          "Address01":"123 ABC Ave",
          "City":"New York City",
          "Country":"US"
        }
      },
      {
        "MetaDataType":"ClientContact",
        "Properties" : 
        {
          "FirstName":"John",
          "LastName":"Doe",
          "Email":"jdoe@example.com",
          "Phone":"8675309"
        }
      }]
   }
}
```

But I want the "Properties" objects to have consistent values based on what the MetaDataType object is defined as and I only want to store the properties for that particular object type in the database attached to that object (there are, across all metadata types, about a hundred unique values).

Hopefully that makes sense, like I said earlier my brain is fried a little today so maybe I am missing something really obvious, but I would like to get your thoughts.

Comment: You upload the value of the JSON object you want to do dynamically, not hard-coded?

Comment: I could allow that, for sure, but the idea of requiring certain fields goes back to reporting and ensuring the fields are available if I wanted to run a report against them, while avoid table sprawl and a really over complicated spiderweb of foreign keys and what not.